# Creating website tour

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-experience

When you sign up on github.com they show a tour that shows everything to start using github properly. Also google shows these tours in Gmail when they add a new feature. These are tiny little boxes, tool-tips float on the page and sometime some key part of the site gets nicely highlighted  by changing the color of either border or background.

My question is, Is there any existing library to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: 
http://amberjack.org/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. I am using [Guiders.js](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS). It completely serves my purpose. Specially the tool tip on different elements is what I was looking for.

**UPDATE: October 3rd, 2013**

Another one I found called [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

Answer (score 1):

My two favorites ones:

- http://revaxarts-themes.com/tour/examples/example6.html
- http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/

If you use bootstrap you may consider: http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 1):

[**Sideshow**](http://fortesinformatica.github.io/Sideshow) is a modern and powerful library for creating interactive tours for web applications and sites.

More than just guiding your users, Sideshow can interact with them:

- Monitor your user's behavior and the state of some screen.
- Create smart steps for your tutorials, which proceeds automatically when some condition is satisfied
- Create relationships between your tutorials, this way, when your user finishes some tutorial, a list with the related tours is shown.
- Use Markdown for rich formatting a step description
- Use events (e.g. beforeStep/afterStep, beforeWizardStarts/afterWizardEnds) to perform some preparation or anything else
- Show contextual tutorials according to the screen being viewed by your user, each tutorial has its own conditions to check if it's eligible for that screen or not

**And other powerful features!**